# ¿Como puedo solucionar el problema que tengo con unos contadores en Python?

Tags: python, algoritmos, ordenamiento

Bien pues estoy intentando aplicar el algoritmo Radix Sort en Python y necesito contar la cantidad de comparaciones y de pasos o intercambios que hace el algoritmo para organizar cierto vector. Tengo el problema de que los pasos siempre son iguales al número de comparaciones cuando no debería ser así y no sé cómo puedo solucionarlo agradecería mucho cualquier sugerencia o corrección.

Este es mi código, cabe mencionar que no uso ningún tipo de función.

```
arr = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 13, 20, 19, 22, 24, 29, 25, 32, 35, 39, 37, 36, 41, 43, 42, 44, 50, 46, 49, 45, 51, 53, 54, 57, 56, 55, 58, 61, 67, 64, 69, 71, 81, 77, 78, 73, 87, 99, 88, 89, 91, 90, 96, 97, 98]

max_num = max(arr)
exp = 1
n = len(arr)
comparaciones = 0 
pasos = 0  

while max_num // exp > 0:
     count = [0] * 10
     output = [0] * n

for i in range(n):
    index = arr[i] // exp
    count[index % 10] += 1

for i in range(1, 10):
    count[i] += count[i - 1]

i = n - 1

while i >= 0:
    index = arr[i] // exp
    output[count[index % 10] - 1] = arr[i]
    count[index % 10] -= 1
    i -= 1
    comparaciones += 1  

for i in range(n):
    arr[i] = output[i] 
    pasos += 1

exp *= 10

print("Arreglo ordenado:")
print(arr)
print("Comparaciones:", comparaciones)
print("Pasos:", pasos)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) no hace comparaciones, si observas, no hay ni un solo `if` en todo el código.

En esta línea es que se hacen los intercambios:

```py
output[count[index % 10] - 1] = arr[i]
```

Sin embargo, no le importa si el elemento actual es el mismo con el que se va a "intercambiar", simplemente lo sobreescribe sin más. Entonces la cantidad de pasos será `cantidad de digitos de max(arr)` y la cantidad de intercambios:
`len(arr) * cantidad_pasos`

El código está "bien", pero mal indentado. Debe ser:

```py
max_num = max(arr)
exp = 1
n = len(arr)
comparaciones = 0 # <-- Intercambios
pasos = 0  

while max_num // exp > 0:
    count = [0] * 10
    output = [0] * n

    for i in range(n):
        index = arr[i] // exp
        count[index % 10] += 1

    for i in range(1, 10):
        count[i] += count[i - 1]

    i = n - 1
    while i >= 0:
        index = arr[i] // exp
        output[count[index % 10] - 1] = arr[i]
        count[index % 10] -= 1
        i -= 1
        comparaciones += 1  

    for i in range(n):
        arr[i] = output[i]
    
    pasos += 1
    exp *= 10

print("Arreglo ordenado:")
print(arr)
print("Comparaciones:", comparaciones)
print("Pasos:", pasos)
```

El resultado es:

```
Arreglo ordenado:
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 13, 19, 20, 22, ...., 98, 99 ]
Comparaciones: 100
Pasos: 2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclarar la situación, sin embargo, entonces según el resultado el algoritmo haría 100 intercambios y solo dos comparaciones o como debe ser?